# Dereference a ReferenceField in Mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine, objectid, dbref

I am trying to dereference a reference field on my Flask backend and return the complete object with that certain field dereferenced.

The field I am trying to dereference is defined like this:

```
vouches_received = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField('Vouch'))
```

The way I am trying to dereference it is like this:

```
unverified_vouches = []
for vouch in usr.vouches_received:
    unverified_vouches.append(vouch.to_mongo())

usr.vouches_received = unverified_vouches
```

However, when I then do:

```
usr.to_json()
```

On the object, then I get a ValidationError like so:

```
ValidationError: u'{...}' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a
12-byte input of type 'str' or a 24-character hex string
```

The 3 dots (...) is basically the document dereferenced, it has mostly Strings, a Date Field, and some other reference fields I do not wish to dereference.

I am aware this is a valid error, as it is expecting an ObjectID for the reference field, but then arises the question, how do I succeed at dereferencing that field and return the document.

Thanks

Comment: what are you intending to do with the usr object after you have converted it to json?

Comment: return it to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListField` is expecting elements of `ObjectId` and because you've de-referenced them it throws that error. I'm not sure this is the most elegant way but could you convert the `usr.to_json()` to a `dict` and then replace the `vouches_received` list with a deferenced list afterwards - I can't test it but something like?

```
user_dict = json.loads(usr.to_json())

unverified_vouches = []
for vouch in usr.vouches_received:
    user_dict['vouches_received'].append(vouch.to_mongo())

usr_json = json.dumps(user_dict)
```

A better solution may be to use an EmbededDocument.

Comment: I indeed tried your approach, but now unfortunately I am receiving the error: TypeError: ObjectId('556f474ff6e6af0009161525') is not JSON serializable
As there are other ObjectIds in my Vouch object

Comment: Ok got it! instead of json.dumps we can do bson.json_util.dumps and it solves that issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Easy to forget that mongodb is actually bson